# Force video/webm mime type using .htaccess based on request uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mime-types, webm

I have a rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule   (.+?\.fid)/ /$1 [L]
```

with a request URI like: `/123.fid/myfile.webm`

How can I force the mime type to: `video/webm` using .htaccess including the rule above?

What I have attempted already, to add on TOP of the .htaccess file without success:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

and

```
<FilesMatch  "\.webm$">
  ForceType video/webm
</FilesMatch>
```

I use apaches mime_magic module to look up mime type of .fid files, but this doesn't apply to webm files. I'm assuming it's the RewriteRule which is causing problems with the file type, and I need to look for webm in the request uri somehow.

If I do: `AddType video/webm .fid` the correct mime type is sent - but this breaks any other file format stored in .fid. Using .fid is a design requirement and cannot change.

***Edit:**

I also attempted:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.webm$
RewriteRule .* - [T=video/webm]
```

and

```
RewriteRule \.webm$ - [T=video/webm]
```

with the same result. The mime type served is `text/plain`. Could this be mime_magic module interfiering?

I also attempted to add: `DefaultType video/webm` which works. This is the closest thing to a solution currently, as mime_magic module seems to find the correct mime types to send, but I don't find this to be a particularly elegant solution

***Edit2**: `AddType video/webm .fid` IS working - how can I conditionally do AddType based on request uri?

Comment: Are you serving real files, or virtual URLs?

Comment: The .fid files are real files, while I rewrite the url to include myfile.webm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to get this to work in Apache, I gave up and moved to nginx instead. I got it to work in nginx using:

```
location ~\.webm$ {
  add_header Content-Type video/webm;
  rewrite  (.+?\.fid)/ /$1  break;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the T-flag in a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule someRegEx$ - [T=video/webm]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a shot. However, it appears that something is overriding this .htaccess directive somewhere? Unless my syntax is off..

Comment: Is mod_rewrite actually enabled?

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me, when I added the following lines to my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AddType video/ogg .ogv
  AddType video/webm .webm
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This does not work, as the physical file is a .fid file, not .webm - the .webm is only added through rewrite

Comment: thanks this worked for me! although it doesnt answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending the data with a script (not real files) then the script must send the correct headers, for example with PHP (before any other output):

```
header("Content-type: video/webm");
```

In case of real files you can use content-negotiation (instead of rewrite) and:

```
AddType video/webm .fid
```

**Edit:**

Unfortunately I'm not near apache, but this might worth a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.webm$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=is_webm:true]

Header set Content-Type video/webm env=is_webm
```

Comment: I am not sending files through script. The files are actual files with file ending .fid (and contains a variety of data types)

Comment: If you had read my post a bit more carefully you should have noticed: "If I do: AddType video/webm .fid the correct mime type is sent - but this breaks any other file format stored in .fid. Using .fid is a design requirement and cannot change."

Comment: @Jon Did you have a chance to try the *mod_headers* solution?

Comment: Your suggestion resulted in the same `text/plain` header