# Change content type via htaccess with addtype for an url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, add-type

Is it possible to change the content type of a url via the htaccess file?

I'v got name.tld/foo/bar which has the content type html in the header informations. thats a mod rewrited site from a cms. including xml data structure. but this should get an xml header to be valid. unfortunately I can not do that in the code, because this is rendered out of a terrible cms.

so i will try to do that with AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' .html ... but not for all html files. is it possible to add an url instead of .html?

Comment: a little tweak on this can give you an answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169002/force-video-webm-mime-type-using-htaccess-based-on-request-uri

Comment: RewriteRule someRegEx$ - [T=text/xml]

so: 

RewriteRule /foo/bar$ - [T=text/xml]
?

that doesn't work.